# Express reflection w.r.t. combination of vectors as combinations of reflection w.r.t. vectors

Tags: euclidean-geometry, rotations, reflection, clifford-algebras, coxeter-groups

Let $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^m$, then for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$ we call reflection of $x$ w.r.t. $\alpha$ the reflection of $x$ w.r.t. the hyperplane $\alpha^\perp=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^m\mid <\alpha,y>=0\}$ and we denote it with $\sigma_\alpha(x)$. Then we can compute $\sigma_\alpha(x)$ as
$$
\sigma_\alpha(x)=x-2\frac{<x,\alpha>}{|\alpha|^2}\alpha=-\alpha x\alpha^{-1},
$$
where in the last equation we used the Clifford product on $\mathbb{R}^m$. Note that $\sigma_\alpha$ does not depend on $|\alpha|$.
My question is the following: let $\{e_1,...,e_m\}$ denote an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^m$, is there any convenient way to express $\sigma_\alpha=\sigma_{\alpha_1e_1+...+\alpha_me_m}$ in terms of $\sigma_{e_i}$? Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't think so. Assuming $\alpha_i$ are vectors and $e_i$ are scalars, or vice versa, even if the vectors are non-zero it's possible that the sum $\sum_i\alpha_ie_i$ is zero. For comparison, you might ask for the inverse of a sum of numbers in terms of the inverses of the individual numbers.

Comment: If you just use $-\alpha x\alpha$, with no inverse, then we might be able to get a formula, but of course it would need to be re-scaled.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how is this important. However $e_1,...,e_m$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^m$, hence the sum cannot be zero unless all the components are zero.

Comment: Okay, it wasn't clear that $e_i$ are a basis. -- Representing the reflection transformations as matrices, we have $$\sigma_{e_1}=\begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},\quad\sigma_{e_2}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$$ but $$\sigma_{e_1+e_2}=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}$$ which is not a linear combination of the other two. -- What kind of expression would you consider "convenient"? That question must be answered before your question can be answered.

Comment: @mr_e_man I was thinking about some linear combination. But thanks to your example, I think this is not possible.